# i made changes to nginx config but it goes back to original (proxy_pass)

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, vps, nginx-config, proxypass

I have a VPS and I Installed nginx (reverse proxy) through WHM panel. Next step , I configured config file for set the proxy_pass.
[image: file configuration]

And edit change value "proxy_pass"
[image: editing config file]

It works a few minutes.

but after (minutes or hours) restore automatically a original file and my changes disappear

Has it happened to someone on a VPS? (My vps is hostgator)
Thank you